# Drag and drop between frames - chrome

Tags: drag-and-drop, google-chrome, opera, frames

I have a website http://fewbs.com. I have a shortcuts (bookmarks) section onto the left. Here I provide menus and submenus and drag and drop of shortcuts and menus. Though I have been able to do it in IE and FF but its not working for opera and chrome.

In IE it works by default, in FF by using `-moz-user-focus: ignore; -moz-user-select: none;`.

Can anyone suggest how may I be able to achieve the same in opera and chrome?

Answer (score 0):

In Internet Explorer and Opera, use the unSelectable attribute for similar functionality. 
In Internet Explorer, Google Chrome and Safari, there is another possibility to make an element unselectable. If the onselectstart event is canceled, the selection process does not start. 
For further details, please see the unSelectable attribute and the onselectstart event.

source http://help.dottoro.com/lcrlukea.php